# Efficient way to convert only specific values

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, casting, rounding

So lets say I have an array of strings:

```
string[] values = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "1.5", "56.5", "8" };
```

Lets say I have to loop through these values and do the following operations:

1. Round it to the nearest even number (if it's a double only)
2. After rounding remove the fractional part of the number.
3. If the number is negative remove the sign.

```
string[] values = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "1.5", "56.5", "8" };

for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    file[i].Value = ((Int32)Math.Abs(Math.Round(Double.Parse(values[i]), MidpointRounding.ToEven))).ToString();
}
```

which is basically the same as doing this:

```
string[] values = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "1.5", "56.5", "8" };

for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    String strValue = values[j];
    Double dblValue = Double.Parse(strValue);
    Double dblRoundedValue = Double.Parse(dblValue);
    Int32 intValue = (Int32)dblRoundedValue;
    Int32 intAbsValue = Math.Abs(intValue);
    String finalValue = intAbsValue.ToString();

    file[i].Value = finalValue;
}
```

There could be over a million values in that array so is there a way to make this process more efficient?

Comment: I think you mean whole number (even could mean like even or odd)

Comment: @Blam - No, he means even.  56.5 rounds to 56. 57.5 rounds to 58.

Comment: @Blam Whole numbers are (0, 1, 2, 3, ....), I meant Round the number to the nearest even number, it's a rounding technique.

Comment: Even for "over a million values", I'd suggest you _try_ it first and see what your performance is like. _Then_ if it's too slow, get an idea of how much faster it needs to be. Without a validly _large_ sample size, it will be difficult to determine "how much faster" any changes you make to it are, or if they are even optimizations _at all_

Comment: What type of efficiency are you looking for?  Run time, memorary usage, code readability, code reuse, etc...?

Comment: That depends on how you define "more efficient". It is probably possible to be slick and speed up the number of CPU cycles per iteration, but you'll still need to traverse the entire list. So regardless you're still looking at an O(n) operation.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Ok let me check how much times it takes to go thorugh 10 million values which is the typical load...

Comment: Regarding the even rounding, the [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method uses "Banker's Rounding" (which rounds to the nearest even number for midpoints). I'm not sure what you want though Eric for non-midpoints: would 57.4 round to 58 or 57? Furthermore, I think you may have a typo in your code/question: `Double dblRoundedValue = Double.Parse(dblValue);` should this be `Double dblRoundedValue = Math.Round(dblValue);`?

Comment: In what ways is the code that you have insufficient?

Comment: @Mark I would presume a nullable string

Comment: @MartinCapodici Based on  the Int32 casting, I assumed a nullable int so I have some concerns about boxing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I tried some things, and using a combination of older-than-the-supernova's suggestion of checking for a decimal point in the string before considering if it was necessary to parse it to a Double, and Andrew Cooper's suggestion of using Parallel.For I got results of

```
Init...Done
Simple
20024
LookingAtString
8082
ParallelConvertLookingAtString
3559
Simple
19552
LookingAtString
7985
ParallelConvertLookingAtString
3595
```

with the following code...

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const int nNumbers = 20000000;

        static string[] values = new string[nNumbers];
        static string[] file = new string[nNumbers];

        static Random rand = new Random();

        // Create some sample data.
        static void Init()
        {
            string sgn = "";
            for (int i = 0; i <= nNumbers - 1; i++)
            {
                sgn = rand.Next(51) == 1 ? "-" : "";

                if (rand.Next(4) == 1)
                {
                    values[i] = sgn + (rand.NextDouble() * 100).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    values[i] = sgn + rand.Next(100);
                }
            }
        }

        static void ConvertSimple()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= nNumbers - 1; i++)
            {
                file[i] = Math.Abs(Math.Round(double.Parse(values[i]), MidpointRounding.ToEven)).ToString();
            }
        }

        static void ConvertLookingAtString()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= nNumbers - 1; i++)
            {
                if (values[i].IndexOf('.') >= 0)
                {
                    file[i] = Math.Abs(Math.Round(double.Parse(values[i]), MidpointRounding.ToEven)).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    file[i] = values[i].TrimStart('-');
                }

            }

        }

        static void ParallelConvertLookingAtString()
        {
            Parallel.For(0, nNumbers, i =>
            {
                if (values[i].IndexOf('.') >= 0)
                {
                    file[i] = Math.Abs(Math.Round(double.Parse(values[i]), MidpointRounding.ToEven)).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    file[i] = values[i].TrimStart('-');
                }

            });

        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("Init...");
            Init();
            Console.WriteLine("Done");

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            // run each test twice

            for (int testNum = 0; testNum < 2; testNum++)
            {
                sw.Reset();
                sw.Start();
                ConvertSimple();
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Simple\n" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

                sw.Reset();
                sw.Start();
                ConvertLookingAtString();
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("LookingAtString\n" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

                sw.Reset();
                sw.Start();
                ParallelConvertLookingAtString();
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("ParallelConvertLookingAtString\n" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Please note that that is using twenty million samples rather than the one million-ish you suggest, and about one third of the values are fractional, and about two percent are negative. You didn't give the expected fraction of those, so I made something up.

Some bits may be non-optimal C# because I converted it from VB. Run on an Intel Core i7 920 with 6GB of RAM, compiled to run on x64.

**Edit:** Oh yeah, so my answer is the above `ParallelConvertLookingAtString` method.

Answer (score 5):

This operation is inherently parallelizable (if that's a word).  A `Parallel.ForEach` loop, parallel Linq pipeline, or something similar, would improve execution time.

```
string[] values = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "1.5", "56.5", "8" };

var file = values.AsParallel()
                 .Select(s => Double.Parse(s))
                 .Select(d => (int)Math.Round(d))
                 .Select(i => Math.Abs(i).ToString())
                 .ToArray();
```

Comment: Probably faster, but technically not any more efficient.

Comment: @Shoe: True, but Eric has clarified that he wants better "Run time" efficiency, which I surmise means to reduce the time taken.

Comment: @Andrew Cooper The run time was reduced from 10 seconds to 5 so I guess that's a 50% improvement, I Parallel works better if it's a high load...

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason that you do the individual `.Select()` statements over doing `.ForAll()` with a delegate? I only ask because I'm curious which one would be more efficient.

Comment: I'm running some tests now

Comment: @BenBlack - I tested with a single select that does all the work in go, like the OP's first sample, and saw no appreciable difference in performance.  I think the chaining of multiple selects adds to readability, in that each step of the transformation is clearly seen.

Comment: Fair enough, in my tests your code is a bit faster than a delegate, but that just could be because of the way I coded it, plus it is much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
Double dblValue;
Double dblRoundedValue;
Int32 intValue;
Int32 intAbsValue;
String finalValue;
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    strValue = values[j];
    if (!Int32.TryParse(strValue, out intValue))
    {
        //dblValue = Double.Parse(strValue);
        //dblRoundedValue = Double.Parse(dblValue);
        //intValue = (Int32)dblRoundedValue;
        intValue = (Int32)(Double.Parse(strValue));
    }
    //intValue  = Math.Abs(intValue);
    //finalValue = intValue .ToString();

    file[i].Value = (Math.Abs(intValue)).ToString();
}
```

But I don't understand the two Double.Parse.
Put em back in if you need them
And convert this to a parallel

```
ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions();
parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 16;
Parallel.For(0, values.Length, parallelOptions, i =>
{
   strValue = values[j];
   if (!Int32.TryParse(strValue, out intValue))
   {
      intValue = (Int32)(Double.Parse(strValue));
   }
   if (intValue < 0) intValue = -intValue;
   file[i].Value = intValue.ToString();
});
```

I think grunge will be the fastest

```
string[] values = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "1.5", "56.5", "8" };
string[] files = new string[values.Length];
HashSet<char> lt5 = new HashSet<char> {'0','1','2','3','4'};
bool haveDecimal;
bool haveDecimalConfirmed;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    sb.Clear();
    haveDecimal = false;
    haveDecimalConfirmed = false;
    foreach(char c in values[i])
    {
        if (haveDecimal)
        {
            if (lt5.Contains(c))
            {
                files[i] = sb.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                files[i] = (Int32.Parse(sb.ToString()) + 1).ToString();
            }
            haveDecimalConfirmed = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (c == '.')
        {
            haveDecimal = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (c == '-') continue;
        sb.Append(c);
    }
    if (!haveDecimalConfirmed) files[i] = sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Good answer, I'd also only do Math.Abs if (intValue < 0)

Comment: @EricBergman I thought about that but not sure that check would be worth it.

Comment: So you're saying that a check could take more time than the Math.Abs operation, I guess I have to test and see.

Comment: A check would be faster than an abs but it is an extra step.  Assume twice as fast.  If exactly 1/2 are negative then a wash.  The two checks saved the one abs.

Comment: any timing test results?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas:

1. If you have a million values and you expect a lot of repeats then you can build up a Hashtable of previous results that you can reuse.

I tested this and it is much faster if you have say all the elements the same. It is probably faster with a small number of distinct elements. However if the elements are all different it uses a lot of memory and you would want to cap it once the Hash gets too big.

1. If you are sure of the formatting locale, then you can do this:

A string is a character array. Instead of converting to double, iterate though the characters until you reach the first "." then take the next digit. Convert the text (ignoring any -) before the . to an integer. If the value after the . is 5,6,7,8,9 then add 1 to that integer.

Example:

```
Input: "-1002.55"

Text between - and . is: "1002"
Converted to int this is: 1002
Character immediately after . is: "5"
Result: 1002 + 1 = 1003
```

That is for round to nearest. If you need to round to nearest even number look at digit immediately before . and if there is one after, and the digit before . is 1,3,5,7,9 then add to the final number.

Comment: No way the time to populate a hashtable and lookup is worth it.  This is a very fast conversion.

Comment: @Blam, hashtable lookup is very fast too. The number conversion we are doing is parsing strings and casting. I can't see how that is going to be faster than hash lookup.

Comment: Then test it out.  And do the math.  Even if the lookup is faster (which I seriously doubt it is) you have to account for the time to populate the hastable and the wasted lookups that are not in the table.  And you still need to convert each value once.

Comment: Note I said "and you expect a lot of repeats", with 10 million elements, all the same, on my machine, it takes 11648k ticks as is and 2068k ticks with the hash improvement.

Comment: You really think 10 million elements all the same is a fair comparison?

Comment: @Blam. It is an extreme. If it failed in the extreme I can happily remove my answer. However it didn't, and in fact it was much faster. So I would assume (without testing) that low cardinalities such as 1,10 or even 10000 would show this as faster, where as high cardinalities such as 90% of the total elements, will show this as slower.

Answer (score -3):

Assuming you mean "even number" to mean "nearest integer" and not "integer multiple of 2".
Assuming you mean to remove negative sign from all numbers as opposed to only numbers you have rounded.

You assume that your input strings are always valid Double format, is that reasonable? Assuming there are no numbers formatted with scientific notation, examine each input string for a decimal point, its faster than parsing and a test for a fractional part. No decimal point, no rounding needed.

Comment: Looks like a comment and not an answer.

Comment: +1 As my testing suggests that checking if `values(i).IndexOf('.') >= 0` makes the `Double.Parse` necessary, with a population of approximately one third fractional values (sample size: 100,000) makes it considerably faster.